# Error while updating the project from Nuxeo Studio

Tags: nuxeo

I am getting following error whenver I try to update my studio project from Nuxeo Platform. Earlier I was getting a transaction timeout error and I increased the nuxeo.db.transactiontimeout to 900. But now I see this error as below.

Also, when I stop and start the nuxeo server, in the summary tab I see that one the application fails to start. There is also an error An error was detected during startup = Component Loading Status: Pending: 0 / Missing: 0 / Unstarted: 1 / Total : 770

Comment: Also there is following error also unknown connection org.nuxeo.ecm.core.storage.sql.ra.ConnectionImpl@72917a26 in org.nuxeo.ecm.core.storage.sql.ra.ManagedConnectionImpl@788beb09

Comment: Which error do you get?